# Is there a practicle use of worklight FormBasedAuthenticator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have gone through IBM Worklight Authentication concepts. Now I have few questions.

1) Is there a practical use of Formbased authenticater ?
All the examples I have seen uses NonValidating Login module which doesn't really validates the credentials. So what if I want to use the Form based authenticator to check the credentials against the db ? Can you please point me to a real world example ?

2) If I choose custom security test for my application, I won't be get the wl_antiXSRFRealm enabled by default, what if I don't use it, is my app vulnerable to attacks ?

3) Read in one of the article "Therefore in case your security configuration is close to default security settings you might want to use webSecurityTest and mobileSecurityTest. "

It means, we are not going to ask the users to enter credentials ?

4) A practical scenario where Custom Login module & Custom Authenticator can be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between either Form-based authentication or adapter-based authentication and the non-validating login module. You could implement them by using non-validating, or by actually validating the user credentials...

Non-validating login module is used in the sample because we cannot supply you a back-end with the sample; the purpose of the sample is to show the implementation of the client-side.

In form-based, the form is returned by the server. In adapter-based and custom-based you are less restricted and can handle this in the client. Either way, you handle the authentication [using a challenge handler](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/).

Also, please read: [Understanding predefined Worklight authentication realms and security tests](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en).

- If you use a custom security test, there is no such thing as "default". You determine which tests will be in it. Simply add it back.
- The antiXSRFRealm has got nothing to do with user credentials and your login module.
- It is mainly used for Desktop websites and not for mobile devices; if you want, add it back in your custom security test.

Comment: Idan, Thanks for clearing some confusion!! Coming to Form based authentication, can you please elaborate on where exactly we need to write the logic for validating the credentials ? In the case of Adaptor, we are doing it in the adaptor procedure, in the case of Form based authentication ?

Comment: My mistake. In form-based authentication as well, you need to create a challenge handler. See here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/form-based-authentication/

Comment: Idan, I know we need a challenge handler component. But where should I write the code that validates the credentials (In case of form based authentication) ? Can I write that logic inside the challenge handler ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can.

Comment: In which method of the challenge handler ?

Comment: I don't know. See if you can find your answer in the docs and in the above link.